# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 Android error

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am Creating an ArrayAdapter's Super class in which I am binding the data I receive from the object and put them into the TextViews.
The code is not any complicated and I have double checked the ids of all the TextViews in my XML.

And I have checked all the other questions with the same title.
None of them seem to work in this case.

Attaching my code below.

```
public class EarthquakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Earthquake> 
    {
        public EarthquakeAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
        }
        public EarthquakeAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Earthquake> Earthquakes)
        {
            super(activity,0, (List<Earthquake>) Earthquakes);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            View ListItemView = convertView;
            if(ListItemView == null)
            {
                ListItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.earthquake_list_item, parent, false);
            }

            Earthquake currentItem = getItem(position);

            TextView magnitude = (TextView) 
            ListItemView.findViewById(R.id.magnitude);
            //Double m = ;
            magnitude.setText(""+currentItem.getmMag());

            TextView location = (TextView) ListItemView.findViewById(R.id.Location);
            location.setText(currentItem.getmLocation());

            TextView date = (TextView) ListItemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            date.setText(currentItem.getmDate());

            return ListItemView;
        }
```

and then there is the xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_view_container">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magnitude"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="7.6"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Location"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="San Fransisco"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="Date"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Earthquake Class.

```
public class Earthquake 
     {
        private double mMag;
        private String mLocation;
        private String mDate;

        public Earthquake(double Mag, String Location, String Date){
            mMag = Mag;
            mLocation = Location;
            mDate = Date;
        }

        public String getmDate() {
            return mDate;
        }

        public double getmMag() {
            return mMag;
        }

        public String getmLocation() {

            return mLocation;
        }
    }
```

and This is the Error LOG.

```
06-11 20:38:36.570 9359-9359/com.example.android.quakereport W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000 06-11 20:38:36.571 9359-9359/com.example.android.quakereport D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 06-11 20:38:36.581 9359-9359/com.example.android.quakereport E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.quakereport, PID: 9359
   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1369)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:145)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2824)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1183)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:378)
       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
       at com.example.android.quakereport.EarthquakeAdapter.getView(EarthquakeAdapter.java:28)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1876)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1685)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2680)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2198)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1958)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6045)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:608)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Comment: Please show us your Earthquake class and the logcat as well

Comment: I am unable to understand where are you setting values in Earthquake class to the variables mMag,mLocation,mDate? I think you need to set values while calling constructor

Comment: @AkhilSaraswat It's an arraylist passed to the constructor...

Comment: Remove the `super` call in `getView()`. You've passed an invalid layout resource ID in the three-argument constructor - which is leading to that Exception when `ArrayAdapter` tries to inflate it - and you're not using the `super` return anyway, since you're inflating the layout yourself.

Comment: @MikeM. Your comment helped. It'ss not showing any errors. thankyou. :D 

And thanks everyone for helping. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the getView() method of EarthquakeAdapter class
the statement super.getView() was causing some issue. I removed it and its working fine now.

Refer to the comment of @MikeM in the question itself.

> Remove the super call in getView(). You've passed an invalid layout resource ID in the three-argument constructor - which is leading to that Exception when ArrayAdapter tries to inflate it - and you're not using the super return anyway, since you're inflating the layout yourself

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to fix your constructors. You only need one.

```
public class EarthquakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Earthquake> {
    public EarthquakeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
        super(context, 0, earthquakes);
    }
```

And you should not need to call `super.getView`

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Earthquake earthquake = getItem(position);

        View v = convertView;
        if(v == null) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.earthquake_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Otherwise, you need to determine what is happening at line 28 and what is zero valued there.

You may follow this example to [define custom adapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#defining-the-adapter)

You may need to clean and rebuild the project to regenerate your resources.

Comment: Actually, it was the statement with super.getView() call. 
I deleted it. Its now working. Thank you. :)

Comment: Yeah I thought you meant the super constructor

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Earthquake currentItem = new Earthquake(3.33,"someplace","05-05-05")
     currentItem=getItem(position);
```

in place of

```
 Earthquake currentItem = get(position);        `//getItem(position);`
```

if it work you need to set values of the variables declared in Earthquake class

This might solve your problem
Declare member variables

```
Context ctx;
ArrayList<Earthquake> Earthquake;
    public EarthquakeAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Earthquake> Earthquakes)
            {
               super(activity,0, (List<Earthquake>) Earthquakes);
               Ctx=activity;
               Earthquake=this.Earthquake; 
            }
```

now where you are doing `Earthquake currentItem = getItem(position);`
do this

```
Earthquake currentItem=Earthquake.get(position);     `//getItem(position);`
```

basically you are not passing values received by EarthquakeAdapter.

Also check in this

```
    public Object getItem(int position) {
            return Earthquake.get(position);
        }
public int getCount() {
        return Earthquake.size();
    }
public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

If this does not work show the code where you are setting the `ArrayList<Earthquake>` and calling adapter `public EarthquakeAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Earthquake> Earthquakes)`

Comment: but getItem(int) is not a method of Earthquake class. How can call it through an object of it?

Comment: apologies my mistake

Comment: How does making a `new Earthquake` solve the problem?

Comment: It will not solve your problem but if it works then the array list is not parsing properly to the constructor otherwise I might be wrong so kindly check that

Comment: If it doesn't solve but helps, you should post it as a comment. Not an answer

Comment: i'll be careful next time

Comment: You realize this is [the wrong way](https://medium.com/@Sudhagar/android-array-adapters-what-most-of-the-tutorials-don-t-tell-you-90f898fb54a2) to write adapter anyway?