# The get view method crashes before generating the objects

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

The get view method from the script below crashes everytime I ran the app  (the error points to that method ) this is the error :

```
07-11 17:25:01.147 8512-8512/com.example.android.quakereport E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                       
Process: com.example.android.quakereport, PID: 8512                                                                       
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

and this is the ArrayAdapter from the getview method code :

```
public class EarthQuakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Earthquake> {

public EarthQuakeAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Earthquake> Earthquakes) {
    // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
    // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
    // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
    // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
    super(context, 0, Earthquakes);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
    Earthquake currentEarthquake = getItem(position);
    TextView magnitude = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.magnitude);
    // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
    // set this text on the name TextView
    magnitude.setText(Earthquake.getmMagnitude());


    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
    TextView place = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Place);        // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
    // set this text on the number TextView
    place.setText(Earthquake.getMplace());

    // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID list_item_icon
    TextView date = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
    date.setText(Earthquake.getmDate());
    // Get the image resource ID from the current AndroidFlavor object and
    // set the image to iconView


    // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an ImageView)
    // so that it can be shown in the ListView
    return listItemView;





}
```

I can add any code or ressource if needed just tell me on the comments.

Comment: Which line is causing the crash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486096/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x0-android-error)

Comment: I didn't understand your comment @Bucket

Comment: @OussamaHassini Read the question and the answers at the link provided in my above comment. This question has been asked before. Your code is remarkably similar.

Answer (score 1):

You're never really returning the ViewHolder you inflated.

You shouldn't call `super` when the view is null. You should inflate it, get the child views, populate them and finally return the inflated root view.

Take a look [at the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView) to learn more about this process.

Try to write the adapter like this:

```
public class EarthQuakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Earthquake> {

    // ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        Earthquake currentEarthquake = getItem(position);
        TextView magnitude = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.magnitude);
        // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the name TextView
        magnitude.setText(Earthquake.getmMagnitude());


        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
        TextView place = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Place);        // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the number TextView
        place.setText(Earthquake.getMplace());

        // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID list_item_icon
        TextView date = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
        date.setText(Earthquake.getmDate());
        // Get the image resource ID from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set the image to iconView


        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an ImageView)
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

You can read more about smooth scrolling [here on android's training page](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling).
And as an option, you could switch to RecyclerView, [you can read more about it here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).

Comment: Thank you for your remarkable help I just wanted to know if I should delete the Earthquake adapter method constructor or know

Comment: No, you keep the constructor, I removed it just for the sake of simplicity

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to call `super.getView(...)` in the overridden `getView` function, and you're passing in an invalid resource ID. Simply remove that line, since you're not using its return value anyway:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: We'll know for sure if you try it